# Error when using pcfromkinect

Tags: matlab, kinect, matlab-cvst, point-clouds, color-depth

I am using a **Kinect for XBOX 360** device. I installed **kinectSDK v1.6** and **kinect for windows support package** in **MATLAB 2015b**. Acquisition of depth and color images is carried out perfectly. However, when I try to use **pcfromkinect** function following error occurs:

```
No public property InputDepthMap exists for class videosource.

Error in imaq.internal.KinectColor2DepthMap

Error in vision.internal.visionKinectColorToSkeleton

Error in pcfromkinect (line 96)
        vision.internal.visionKinectColorToSkeleton(depthDevice, depthImage, colorImage, isDepthCentric);

Error in kinect_image (line 22)
    ptCloud = pcfromkinect(depthDevice,depthImage,colorImage);
```

Does this function support **Kinect for XBOX 360** devices?

Source code of my program is as follows:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

try
    % Create System objects for the Kinect device.
    colorDevice = imaq.VideoDevice('kinect',1);
    depthDevice = imaq.VideoDevice('kinect',2);

    % Change the returned type of color image from single to unint8.
    colorDevice.ReturnedDataType = 'uint8';

    % Warm up the cameras.
    step(colorDevice);
    step(depthDevice);

    % Load one frame from each device. The initial frame executes slowly because the objects must wake up the devices.
    colorImage = step(colorDevice);
    depthImage = step(depthDevice);

    % Convert the depth image to a point cloud.
    ptCloud = pcfromkinect(depthDevice,depthImage,colorImage);

    % Align the color image with the depth image.
    alignedColorImage = alignColorToDepth(depthImage,colorImage,depthDevice);

    % Render the point cloud with color. The axis is set to better visualize the point cloud.
    pcshow(xyzPoints,alignedColorImage,'VerticalAxis','y','VerticalAxisDir','down');
    xlabel('X (m)');
    ylabel('Y (m)');
    zlabel('Z (m)');

    % Release the System objects.
    release(colorDevice);
    release(depthDevice);
catch ME

    % Release the System objects.
    release(colorDevice);
    release(depthDevice);

    rethrow(ME);
end
```

Comment: The problem is not yet solved! I am using Win 8.1 64-bit OS. Did any one used Kinect v1 with new depth-related functionalities of MATLAB 2015b ?

Answer (score 1):

As Kinect for windows and Kinect for XBOX 360 are two different hardwares, pcfromkinect function works with Kinect for Windows only. It will not work with gaming console Kinect for XBOX 360. I am working on same line so let me know if u will get results.

Comment: Right. pcfromkinect works with devlopment version kinect only.

Answer (score 0):

This function and the Image Acquisition toolbox do not support the XBOX 360 sensor.

[See supported hardware here.](http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/kinect-windows.html)